# Field with @Value annotation and a single method. Should I make them both static? Why/why not?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, static

I have a simple URL builder class with a method that gets a field value from properties via `@Value` annotation.

```
@Getter
@Component
public class UrlBuilder {

    @Value("${url.api}")
    private String apiUrl;
    @Value("${url.auth}")
    private String authUrl;

    public String buildApiUrl(String urlAppendix, Map<String, String> queryParams){
        UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(apiUrl + urlAppendix);
        if (!isEmpty(queryParams)){
            for (String key : queryParams.keySet()){
                builder.queryParam(key, queryParams.get(key));
            }
        }

        return builder.toUriString();
    }
}
```

Is there a good reason to make the method `static` and use setter value injection on a static field? So far I had the `UrlBuilder` being injected via constructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static fields and static injection are an anti-pattern in general, since they amount to global shared state, and create ordering dependencies and occasionally thread-safety issues. (It's hard to ensure that callers never call the `buildApiUrl` method before static injection takes place.) This is especially true if you're considering using a *non*-static setter method to set this static field, because that means that calling the setter on *one* instance will implicitly modify every *other* instance as well. It's a confusing API; clients will make assumptions based on common practice, and won't notice that their assumptions are wrong unless they really scrutinize the code.

The main reason to consider using a static field is if you have legacy code that isn't integrated with the dependency injection framework. In that sort of situation, you may need to work around the mismatch by creating singleton adapters that forward calls from static methods to dependency-injected beans. But you'll want to do as little of that as you can get away with; it's better to migrate legacy code to use dependency injection, when possible, than to migrate legacy code to use awkward static adapters around dependency injection.

Comment: That explains everything. Thank you. Nevertheless, what would be the best way to handle this? Leave it as it is? So a constructor injection of a class with non-static variable & methods? I guess that ensures the field to be injected in any case.

Comment: Re: "Leave it as it is? So a constructor injection of a class with non-static variable & methods?": Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

I would never suggest creating static methods in spring bean classes, usually in spring framework until creating util classes i would not recommend static methods.

[When to use static methods in Java?](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/When-to-use-static-methods-in-Java)

- The code in the method is not dependent on instance creation and is not using any instance variable.
- A particular piece of code is to be shared by all the instance methods.
- The definition of the method should not be changed or overridden.
  you are writing utility classes which should not be changed.

I would say you don't need any iteration or util method here, just use the spring [MultiValueMap](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/MultiValueMap.html)

```
MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    map.add("A", "B");
    map.add("C", "D");

    UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString("http://localhost:8080");
    builder.queryParams(map);   //http://localhost:8080?A=B&C=D
```